# Pandas: Combining and summing rows based on values from other rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

In a Panda's data frame, I'd like combine all `'other'` rows from `col_2` into a one row for each value from `col_1` by assigning `col_3` the sum of all corresponding values.

**EDIT - Clarification:** In total, I have about 20 columns (where values in those columns is unique for each col_1. there however 80,000 `other` fields; however, there are three columns affecting my question

**Current dataframe `df`:**

```
col_1    col_2    col_3
1        a        30
1        b        25
1        other    1
1        other    5
2        a        321
2        b        1
2        other    45
2        other    52
2        other    17
2        other    8
```

**Desired resultin :**

```
col_1    col_2    col_3
1        a        30
1        b        25
1        other    6
2        a        321
2        b        1
2        other    122
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on col_1 and col_2 and call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
In [188]:    
df.groupby(['col_1','col_2']).sum().reset_index()

Out[188]:
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      a     30
1      1      b     25
2      1  other      6
3      2      a    321
4      2      b      1
5      2  other    122
```

Comment: I'm not the one who gave -1; however, the code isn't eliminating duplication on my larger sample. Note that I have more than 3 columns in my dataframe

Comment: Does `df.set_index(['col_1','col_2']).sum(level=1)` work then? it would be useful to put complete information in your question from the beginning

Comment: @dassouki: to second EdChum's point, if you have an example on which Ed's approach doesn't do what you want it to (it's certainly what I thought you were after), you should find the smallest version of that and edit it into your question.

Comment: @DSM I added a one liner explaining that there are another 20 columns. the data in them is identical for each unique value in col_1

Comment: @dassouki: show, don't tell.  IIUC, you could include an extra column `col_4` where `df["col_4"] = df["col_1"] * 10` or something, and I think this will work if you simply pass every column except col_3, e.g. `df.groupby(df.columns.difference(["col_3"]).tolist()).sum().reset_index()`.  [Note that this, and Ed's, will only work if there are only one a and b per col_1 value, otherwise it'll combine those as well.  We could avoid this if necessary.]